# Spark: Task not Serializable during Filter command because of custom string comparison

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to perform a query on cassandra with Spark.
The system gets a specific value and I want to find other elements in the DB that contain that value. However that value is user generated and it depends on the query (ie it is not predefined, the system receives each time a new one). So it will be defined somewhere in the method as:

```
val id = "ID"
```

The colmn I am going to query is treated as TEXT by the DB but in fact it is a json output and I have to find a specific value in the json fields. So within the spark command I am also turning the content of each row in Json and traversing.

So the query looks like this:

```
    sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","table").where("some_restriction=random")
      .filter(x=> (Json.parse(x.get[String]("content"))\"id")
      .toString.contains(id))
```

This throws an error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:340)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:66)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:70)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:72)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:74)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:76)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:78)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:80)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:82)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:84)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:86)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:88)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:90)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:92)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:94)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:96)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:98)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:100)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:102)
    at <init>(<console>:104)
    at .<init>(<console>:108)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkConf, value: org.apache.spark.SparkConf@6333ac03)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: conf, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkConf)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1b42baf8)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@57ae95ca)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1f4cd72a)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2df807ab)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2379f977)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@568fa096)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@59fb5d3a)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@215867af)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@3ffc2173)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1d070725)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@eb6646e)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@70dd183b)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2d2ece26)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@260f6aef)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@51fba518)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@3204f493)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5b724a76)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@46d50b32)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@5aa0fbd0)
    - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC, $iwC@704c98c)
    - field (class: $line20.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
    - object (class $line20.$read, $line20.$read@53d5e209)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL313, type: class $line20.$read)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@27c93c32)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1e7669b3)
    - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 67 more
```

If instead of using the reference val id, I put the content of id (namely "ID") directly in the function `.toString.contains("ID")`, it works just fine.
However I cannot hardcode ID. It would not be useful to me at all.

I tried to parse the string in a different way, `s$id`, it still didn't work. Any suggestions?

MORE INFO: I just tested in smaller pieces of code and this error is apparently universal when directly using a string reference inside an RDD filter. Smaller example:

```
val rdd =sc.parallelize(List("adb","abhz","kkl","lok"))
val letter : String = "a"
rdd.filter(x=> x.contains(letter))
```

throws same error as above. If I use "a" instead it works perfectly.

Your suggestion

```
scala> val id = "a"
id: String = a

scala> val localId = id
localId: String = a

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("avf","asd","jku"))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[82] at parallelize at <console>:54

scala> rdd.filter(x=>x.contains(localId))
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304) ....
```

Comment: Please read carefully my answer. This was not my suggestion :)

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it and it worked :). Thank you. So you're saying this would only happen within the shell because the scope is undefined?Interesting. I cannot run that exact command on my current machine, so I was testing it in the shell but now that I ran a simpler version of that in the project file (where the statement is to be inside of a function anyway), it worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem :) You should always know the scope that spark is going to serialise. If you're using a method or field of the class inside of DataFrame/RDD,  Spark will try to grab the whole class to distribute the state to all executors. So try to keep that stuff as local as possible like i.e. creating local references. Another option is to define things inside of `object` (Scala singleton).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your `id` is a member of some class. So Spark tries to serialize the whole class for you. To prevent that just assign your `id` field to some local value:

```
def doParse = {
  val localId = id
  sc.cassandraTable("keyspace","table").where("some_restriction=random")
    .filter(x=> (Json.parse(x.get[String]("content"))\"id")
    .toString.contains(localId))
}
```

**UPD**
So please define the method above in REPL as is. And then invoke it like:

```
scala> doParse
```

This will limit the scope that Spark tries to serialise.

Comment: Just tested it. I get the same error. The value I receive, I parse it from json to string (within the same method) and the output is a string through and through. Currently I am testing in the shell so I definitely have a string working.

Comment: Can you please provide a full stacktrace? I know it should be much longer but it points to a particular object and fields that are not serializable. And try to wrap the whole operation into a method like in my snippet instead of pointing to value allocated in REPL.

Comment: I just did. I also did a test on a smaller scale and the same results appear (detailed at the bottom of the post).

Comment: Because you run everything in REPL, and seems like you still trying to use `id` field out of the method instead of assigning it to `localId` like in my example, Spark tries to grab the whole context. So in REPL beside your `id` there are SparkConf, SparkContext and a lot of other stuff allocated. All those are not serialisable. Please follow my suggestion. Just assign it to a local value and use the local value in `contains` method instead of original `id`.

Comment: I did try it. I'll update directly above what I did in my console.

Comment: wrong thing. you're allocating a `localId` in the same way like original `id`. Look at my example again. Define the method like I in my snippet in a REPL. And just invoke it like `scale> doParse`.